# How to run "node server.js" in Cordova build application

Tags: javascript, cordova, socket.io, p2p

I'm new to cordova and node . I need a signaling server for my cordova application. I am trying to use socket.io-p2p. i am able to run this on browser by executing "node server.js" on command line to run the server.js which acts as the signaling server. But i do not know how to implement this in cordova build apk.

**server.js**

```
var ecstatic = require('ecstatic')
var server = require('http').createServer(
ecstatic({ root: __dirname, handleError: false })
)
var p2pserver = require('socket.io-p2p-server').Server
var io = require('socket.io')(server)

server.listen(8080, function () {
console.log('Listening on 8080')
})

io.use(p2pserver)

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('peer-msg', function (data) {
console.log('Message from peer: %s', data)
socket.broadcast.emit('peer-msg', data)
})

socket.on('peer-file', function (data) {
console.log('File from peer: %s', data)
socket.broadcast.emit('peer-file', data)
})

socket.on('go-private', function (data) {
socket.broadcast.emit('go-private', data)
})
})
```

Comment: Check https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore-cordova